# Magento2: How to get config variable in block.php

Tags: magento2, blocks, configuration

I want to get the value of config variable in my custom `block.php` file.

Can somebody help me in this?

So far, I did following this in my block file.

```
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

But I'm still not getting the value and showing error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   dispatch() on null in
>   D:\wamp64\www\deboomhut0710\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php
>   on line 644 ( ! ) Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null
>   in
>   D:\wamp64\www\deboomhut0710\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php
>   on line 644

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because your block needs to extend at least `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` which is not the case.

It should look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class MyBlock extends AbstractBlock {

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
     array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Error has gone but still not able to get the config value. I want to get the minimum amount set for free shipping at backend.

Comment: @Deeps well your code to get the config value is totally valid. I'm not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: @Deeps are you sure you saved the configuration for the right store ?

Comment: Can you please post your block file here ? @Deeps

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code :

```
const SUBTOTAL = 'carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal';

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
)
{    
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

}
public function getSubtotal() {
 $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
 return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::SUBTOTAL, $storeScope); //you get your value here
}
```

Then in your template file try to get  : $this->getSubtotal();